# How to get the Current Date in ReactNative?

Tags: ios, date, time, react-native, nsdate

I am building my first ReactNative iOS and Android app. I am an iOS coder with Swift and Obj-C. How do I fetch the current date using ReactNative.

Shall I use Native Modules or is there an ReactNative API from which I can get this data ?

Comment: Just `new Date().toDateString()`, reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: reminds me this: https://howtodoinjava.files.wordpress.com/2013/04/use-jquery.gif

Comment: Doesn't work. I am naive in JS and React. Could you please be more elaborate ?

Comment: Use Luxon, a good and modern JS-Library to make working with dates even easier, check out http://moment.github.io/luxon/ and http://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/manual/install.html

Answer (score 70, accepted):

The JavaScript runtime in React Native has access to date information just like any other environment.  As such, simply:

```
new Date()
```

... will give you the current date.  [Here's the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) on working with dates in JS.

If you want a good JS library to make working with dates even easier, check out [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com/).

Comment: Keep in mind the Android JSC doesn't work well with dates, and you might need a custom JSC to handle stuffs like `toLocaleDateString` if you need internationalisation https://github.com/react-community/jsc-android-buildscripts#international-variant

Answer (score 9):

I used `{new Date()}` was generating `Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid` error  the following date function worked for me.

```
const getCurrentDate=()=>{
 
      var date = new Date().getDate();
      var month = new Date().getMonth() + 1;
      var year = new Date().getFullYear();
 
      //Alert.alert(date + '-' + month + '-' + year);
      // You can turn it in to your desired format
      return date + '-' + month + '-' + year;//format: d-m-y;
}
```

For more info https://reactnativecode.com/get-current-date-react-native-android-ios-example
It works for ios as well.

Comment: That will return d-m-y, there is no padding.

Comment: @RobG you can change it to your desired format and can design it as well.

Comment: To clarify, the return statement returns d-m-y, your comment says it returns dd-mm-yyyy. It's your stated format.

Answer (score 7):

I think this should work;

```
new Date().toLocaleString()
```

It will return date and time formatted in your local format (usually in the below format);

```
"6/22/2021, 2:59:00 PM"
```

Answer (score 0):

if you get current`milisec` date use `+ new Date()` and if get current use `new Date()`
I hope Help to you
GoodLuk

Answer (score 0):

To Get the current date-time using Date function you just need to call it in the following ways

```
const date = new Date().getDate(); //To get the Current Date
```