# Get Device Time

Tags: javascript, react-native, date

Is there a straight forward way to get the device time using React Native?
Preferably using an API like so:
`device.getCurrentTime()`

The solutions I've seen online use a bunch of libraries and I don't like that especially to do something that just seems so common that it should be apart of the API.

Comment: Because `new Date()` doesn't do the job?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the Current Date in ReactNative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37271356/how-to-get-the-current-date-in-reactnative)

Comment: @RobG based on what I've been seeing, new Date doesn't do the job properly. It doesn't always give you the correct time, if you change the system timezone, it's likely to be off

Comment: @DowenRobinson—Date objects are based on UTC, system settings are used to work out the current UTC date and time. So yes, if the system clock is set to the wrong time or date (allowing for the timezone), the Date will have the wrong time value. The only way to overcome that is to check with an independent source and compensate for network latency if necessary.

Comment: Ok I might have been misguided then - thanks for clearing that up for me G

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use

```
new Date();
```

See this answer:
[How to get the Current Date in ReactNative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37271356/how-to-get-the-current-date-in-reactnative)